# Use Webhook without Firebase

Tags: javascript, seo, content-management-system, firebase

Is it possible to use a different backend with the Webhook CMS?

I love everything about Webhook, but being able to prerender content is an absolute requirement for my project because of SEO considerations. This is unfortunately not possible with Firebase.

Has anyone ever managed to swap out Firebase in Webhook for something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webhook only uses Firebase for the CMS. The deployed sites are pre-generated staticly. This means google will be able to crawl it. Since static sites are themselves the fasted way to deliver content, you'll also have that advantage versus a traditional system.